# Trying to detect collisions between two rectangles in JS

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection, game-physics, game-development

Currently, I am trying to set up collision detection. However, it always doesn't output anything, or only work about 33% of the time and not know what axis the collision was on. 
Here's a few snippets of my code:

```
function isCollideX(rect1, rect2) {
    return rect1.x + momentumX < rect2.x + rect2.width && (rect1.x + rect1.width + momentumX > rect2.x && (rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height && (rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y))); 
}
function isCollideY(rect1, rect2) {
   return rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width && (rect1.x + rect1.width  > rect2.x && (rect1.y + momentumY < rect2.y + rect2.height && (rect1.y + rect1.height + momentumY > rect2.y))); 
}
```

```
 for (i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
                if (isCollideX(platforms[i].getBoundingClientRect(), document.getElementById('spriteNotReal').getBoundingClientRect())) {
                    if (right = true && falling == false) {
                        moveX = platforms[i].getBoundingClientRect().x;
                        momentumX -= 1;
                    }
                    else if (falling == false) {
                        moveX = platforms[i].getBoundingClientRect().right;
                        momentumX = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        moveY = platforms[i].getBoundingClientRect().y;
                        momentumY = 0;
                        onSolidGround = true;
                    }

            }
    }
```

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
        if (event.code == 'KeyW' && (moveY <= 300)) { 
            moveY += 1;
            momentumY = momentumY + 20;
            onSolidGround = false;
            falling = false;
        }
        /*if (event.code == 'KeyS') {
            moveY = moveY - 10;
        }*/
        if (event.code == 'KeyA') {
            momentumX = momentumX - 3;
        }
        if (event.code == 'KeyD') {
            momentumX = momentumX + 3;
        }
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

Comment: I used that. For some reason my code always thinks my character is colliding with an object?

Comment: You've probably inverted the boolean logic.